# Set a different home page for each role?

Tags: 6, users

The Front Page module only appears to work with anon\auth users and I need it for other roles. Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Go to 
[http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/1790/redirect-users-after-login-depending-on-the-users-roles][1]


  [1]: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/1790/redirect-users-after-login-depending-on-the-users-roles

Comment: Go to

http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/1790/redirect-users-after-login-depending-on-the-users-roles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok nevermind, the Front Page description is poor. It apparently does possess the functionality I need.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this exact scenario, but I just did a quick check user roles and permissions are options in the selection rule when making pages with the [Panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels) module.